# WebStorm Dynamically Created Node.js Modules + Intellisense

Tags: javascript, node.js, autocomplete, webstorm

So we have a lot of modules in our own internal Node.js code that kind of work like this:

```
module.exports = function(opts) {
  // do some stuff with opts
  return {
     moduleMethod0: ...,
     moduleMethod1: ...
  };
}
```

The issue with this is that WebStorm can no longer auto-complete our modules when we use this pattern!

Is there a way to help WebStorm out here?

**Edit:**

It seems like WebStorm can work with JSDoc stuff. So that's a good start! I think I can actually figure this out on my own. All I gotta do is find the module and give it all the JSDoc stuff right there.

We have a helper file that instantiates our target module with the `opts` and then passes that around as its module export. I'll just add the JSDoc stuff there and hopefully it'll just work.

Comment: Actually, WebStorm recognizes this pattern if you are using it without additional transformations. So, this should work:
`var x = require('module')(); x. /* suggests module methods here */`

Comment: You're correct! Thank you so much, that does work.

But then I hit another snag. I thought I'd be clever and wrap the module exports in a Proxy to ensure that the module was invoked before any properties were accessed. This then proceeds to kill the auto-complete.

So many decisions to consider... I like the auto-complete but I also like the export being an enforced callable... Alright, I'll have to solve this part myself.

Thanks for your help though!